# Rails api Oauth with separate authorization server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, oauth, oauth-2.0, rails-api

What I have may be a conceptual problem but here is my scenario:

I have a server that uses `OAuth2` to authenticate with a couple of existing `Rails` applications as an `SSO` provider.

I am building a `Rails` `RESTful` web API that will be consumed by one of those applications.

I want this API to use the existing `OAuth2` server to authorize requests.

Now, all the tutorials on using Doorkeeper require you to have a local user store rather then using an external `OAuth2` provider.  So I thought maybe I needed to somehow connect `Omniauth` so that my API acts as both an `OAuth2` provider and consumer.  But really that doesn't seem right as all I really need to do with my API is confirm that the access token is valid.  But I cannot figure out how to do that with an external `OAuth2` provider.

Like I said, my problem could be a conceptual one, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for [OAuth Assertion](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-grants_assertion)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are you looking for [OAuth Assertion](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper-grants_assertion)? –  [tangrufus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3446742/tangrufus) [Aug 29 at 12:43](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275784/rails-api-oauth-with-separate-authorization-server?noredirect=1#comment52449986_32275784)

Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for.